# User defined Copy constructor

Tags: c++

I'm getting compile errors for the below code but the same gets compiled if I remove copy constructor statement.

Could anyone let me know about this behaviour?

```
class MyClass
{
    private:
        int i;
        MyClass(MyClass &);
    public:
        MyClass():i(0){}
};

int main(){
    MyClass obj = MyClass();
    return 0;
}
```

The error is:

```
MyClass.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: MyClass.cpp:15:24: error: no matching function for call to ‘MyClass::MyClass(MyClass)’ MyClass.cpp:15:24: note: candidates are: MyClass.cpp:11:2: note: MyClass::MyClass(MyClass&) MyClass.cpp:11:2: note: no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘MyClass’ to ‘MyClass&’ MyClass.cpp:10:2: note: MyClass::MyClass() MyClass.cpp:10:2: note: candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Answer (score 3):

This is because your copy constructor is private and you did not implement it. you make it public and implement it. You also forget the `const`.

```
class MyClass
{ 
private:
    int i;
public:
    MyClass():i(0){}
    MyClass(MyClass const & o){ i = o.i; }
};

int main(){
    MyClass obj = MyClass();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: GCC `gcc version 4.4.5 20110214`

Comment: @user2797318, you forget `const` in your copy constructor.

Comment: thanks, making it const has sorted it out.

Comment: that error message's generated from source code without the const.  hence: note: candidates are: MyClass.cpp:11:2: note: MyClass::MyClass(MyClass&).  why are you lying to us?

Comment: now you can mark this answer complete.

Answer (score 0):

A private unimplemented copy constructor is used when by a programmer wants to let you know future programmers that they do no intend this object to be copied. Although this is more common to also include a copy constructor in the private section also not implemented like this

```
private:
    obj(const obj& o);
    obj& operator=(const obj& o);
public:
    obj(...) 
    {
        ...
    }
```

If you are getting errors because you are using a library class that has a private copy constructor, and you are trying to copy the object, causing a compiler error

```
error C2248: 'obj::obj' : cannot access private member declared in class 'obj'
error C2248: 'obj::operator =' : cannot access private member declared in class 'obj'
```

then you are not using the class as intended.

If you are making an object yourself and you do want it to be copied, then you need to implement a public constructor, copy constructor and an assignment operator, and then provide the code to implement all three functions.